# Use Numpy polyadd() to add two polynomials

Tags: python, numpy, math

I'm trying to add two polynomials using Numpy's polyadd(), but i'm getting the wrong result

```
a = [60, 51, 64, 38,  9, 79, 96, 81, 11]
e = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
b = np.polyadd(a, e)
b
array([60, 51, 65, 38, 10, 79, 97, 81, 12])
```

Is there an easy way to get the correct result (61, 51, 65, 38, 10, 79, 97, 81, 11) ?

[image]

Numpy treats coefficients from lowest to the highest order right?  So here it should be (60+51x+64x^2+38x^3+9x^4+79x^5+96x^6+81x^7+11x^8)+(1+x^2+x^4+x^6) = 61+51x+65x^2+38x^3+10x^4+79x^5+97x^6+81x^7+11x^8

Comment: The result you're getting is absolutely correct. Why do you think your version is correct?

Comment: Numpy treats coefficients from lowest to the highest order right? So here it should be (60+51x+64x^2+38x^3+9x^4+79x^5+96x^6+81x^7+11x^8)+(1+x^2+x^4+x^6) = 61+51x+65x^2+38x^3+10x^4+79x^5+97x^6+81x^7+11x^8

Comment: Flipped my vote. This is something that drives me up the wall too, but can't be changed for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the docs for different function. [`np.polynomial.polynomial.polyadd`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyadd.html) uses from lowest order to highest from left to right, whereas, [`np.polyadd`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyadd.html) ranks from highest to lowest.

```
>>> a = [60, 51, 64, 38,  9, 79, 96, 81, 11]
>>> e = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
>>> np.polyadd(a, e)
array([60, 51, 65, 38, 10, 79, 97, 81, 12])
>>> np.polynomial.polynomial.polyadd(a,e)
array([61., 51., 65., 38., 10., 79., 97., 81., 11.])
```

The result you are asking for can be obtained using `np.polyadd` by reversing the lists and then reversing the obtained result as suggested by [@Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398771/use-numpy-polyadd-to-add-two-polynomials/60399045#comment106846073_60399045):

```
>>> np.polyadd(a[::-1], e[::-1])[::-1]
array([61, 51, 65, 38, 10, 79, 97, 81, 11])
```

Comment: You might add that the result can also be "corrected" by changing the sense of the vectors: `np.polyadd(a[::-1], e[::-1])[::-1]`

Comment: Thanks, will add.